# Which version of java source code is generated with protoc?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

How do I know which version of java will be generated with protoc ?

I am using 2.4.1 version of protocol buffers. When i generate java files from .proto files. There are generics used in java files which are not allowed in jdk1.4.
I want to generate java files which are compatible with jdk1.4.

Which version of protocol buffers should i use?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I do not have any direct experience of using Protocol Buffers with Java 1.4;
Based on this answer [protocol buffers java 1.4 question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/protobuf/kjSIOYJpUpQ), **None**.

Some of the indpendent (Java-ME) versions i.e. http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-javame/  may well support Java 1.4. Also have a look at all the java ME versions in [Third party add-ons](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/wiki/ThirdPartyAddOns).

**Note:** javame is also listed in this [Question](http://www.mail-archive.com/protobuf@googlegroups.com/msg01867.html)